# Error while opening KML file via google maps mobile: This community map could not be displayed because it contains error

Tags: android, google-maps, blackberry, google-maps-mobile

I am getting this error when I am trying to invoke the Google maps from my app, with kml document.

I am getting the issue of "this community map could not be displayed because it contains error".

If I point to some kml document of Google, it opens fine, but if I use sample kml doc I am getting this error.